# Spring Security deprecate the configuration class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I recently updated the spring bot versions and noticed that the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class has been **deprecated** and I am going to make changes however I have a problem how can I make changes in my code.

And my question is how can I refactor such a piece of code

```
 @Configuration
 public class MyAutoConfiguration {
     @Bean
     @ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class)
     public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter myService() {
         ...
     }
 }
```

As you can see here I am using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` 2 times,and what method could I use to make it work properly in the current version of Spring Configuring WebSecurity?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of doing this is registering a `SecurityFilterChain` bean

you can find detailed information on how to do this in Spring Documentation.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: So it should look like this? 
`@ConditionalOnMissingBean` no longer needs to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class`, and the method name of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will change to `SecurityFilterChain`

Comment: yes, you don't need @ConditionalOnMissingBean.